# Creating object tag via javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create `object` tag via JavaScript and load a url in it.

I am trying this way but its not creating object tag.

```
var object=document.createElement('object');
object.setAttribute('data','http://www.google.com');
object.setAttribute('width','90%');
object.setAttribute('height','90%');
document.body.appendChild(object);
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I want to load some content over a current page using object tag

Comment: It is creating object tag .See this https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ndemh7s3/1/.
But object.setAttribute('data','http://www.google.com'); may get blocked

Comment: @user2181397 I don't see anything in jsfiddle, changed google to other url but still same url not loaded

Comment: url will be blocked because of security reason. But object tags are getting created and appended in body  also just to assure that i have added a class to object tag

Comment: @user2181397 So that means I can't use `object` tag to load url?

Comment: I think Name of Tag should different 'object'

Comment: @ThiepLV I didn't get you, can you elaborate a bit. Thanks

Comment: For example : var object=document.createElement('tag');